# XML Nokogiri Request won't stop auto ordering hash keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am using ruby 2.0.0 and the `Nokogiri` gem. I have the following code:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml['s'].Envelope('xmlns:s' => "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/") {
    xml['s'].Body {
      xml.GetList('xmlns' => "http://tempuri.org/") {
        xml.listRequest('i:type' => "b:NpsListRequest", 'xmlns:a' => "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Services.List", 'xmlns:i' => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", 'xmlns:b' => "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Services.List.Strategies")
      }
    }
  }
end
```

The above is incomplete. I need to pass in an ID to actually make the call, however this is what the above returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <GetList xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <listRequest xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Services.List" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Services.List.Strategies" i:type="b:NpsListRequest"/>
      </GetList>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The issue is with the `<listRequest xmlns:a` code block. In the XML I am creating, I am passing in `i:type` as the first key, however the response is putting `xmlns:a` as the first key. Why is that happening?

Comment: Why is it important what order the parameters to a tag are in? It's the same result in XML.

Comment: @theTinMan You are correct that it does produce the same result. I am curious as to why this happens, more-so for my own education to know if there are best practices around the order that things are structured as I work towards building out sample API Requests in my docs.

Comment: I don't believe there would be a best-practice for how it's ordered. Only a brain-dead XML parser would care. If you let Nokogiri generate the XML it'll do a pretty good job of creating sane output.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Nokogiri Builder to create XML attributes.

The XML specification declares that attribute order is not significant. See the XML Specification specifically [Section 3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) where it says:

```
the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag ... is not significant.
```

Therefore, the specific way it is handled by an XML library is undefined, but all will produce valid results.